# DirectX Texture rendered incorretly

Tags: render, directx-11, texture2d

I'm trying to render a cube with a texture, the cube works, but the texture is weirdly stretched on the front, back, right and left:
[image]

The texture I'm using:
[image]

As you may notice the texture is stretched over the sides.
This is my code (not full, only parts that you may need :D):

How I create the Shader Resource View:

```
//Create Shader Resouce View from file  and sampler
    HR(CreateDDSTextureFromFile(mDevice, L"D:\\DXSDK\\Projects\\Test\\Debug\\brick.dds", NULL, &mSRV));

    //Create Sampler State
    D3D11_SAMPLER_DESC sd;
    ZeroMemory(&sd, sizeof(D3D11_SAMPLER_DESC));
    sd.AddressU = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_WRAP;
    sd.AddressV = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_WRAP;
    sd.AddressW = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_WRAP;
    sd.ComparisonFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_NEVER;
    sd.Filter = D3D11_FILTER_MIN_MAG_MIP_LINEAR;
    sd.MaxLOD = D3D11_FLOAT32_MAX;

    HR(mDevice->CreateSamplerState(&sd, &mSampler));
```

How my create my buffers:

```
    //Create Vertex Buffer
    Vertex vertices[] = {
            //Front face vertices
            { XMFLOAT3(-1.0f, +1.0f, -1.0f), Colors::Blue, XMFLOAT2(0.0f, 0.0f) },
            { XMFLOAT3(+1.0f, +1.0f, -1.0f), Colors::Red, XMFLOAT2(1.0f, 0.0f) },
            { XMFLOAT3(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f), Colors::Yellow, XMFLOAT2(0.0f, 1.0f) },
            { XMFLOAT3(+1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f), Colors::White, XMFLOAT2(1.0f, 1.0f) },
            //Back face vertices
            { XMFLOAT3(-1.0f, +1.0f, +1.0f), Colors::Black, XMFLOAT2(0.0f, 0.0f) },
            { XMFLOAT3(+1.0f, +1.0f, +1.0f), Colors::Violet, XMFLOAT2(1.0f, 0.0f) },
            { XMFLOAT3(-1.0f, -1.0f, +1.0f), Colors::Aqua, XMFLOAT2(0.0f, 1.0f) },
            { XMFLOAT3(+1.0f, -1.0f, +1.0f), Colors::Green, XMFLOAT2(1.0f, 1.0f) }
    };

    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC vbDesc;
    ZeroMemory(&vbDesc, sizeof(D3D11_BUFFER_DESC));
    vbDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    vbDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
    vbDesc.ByteWidth = sizeof(Vertex) * 8;

    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA vbSub;
    ZeroMemory(&vbSub, sizeof(D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA));
    vbSub.pSysMem = vertices;

    HR(mDevice->CreateBuffer(&vbDesc, &vbSub, &mBoxVB));

    //Create Index Buffer
    UINT indices[] = {
        //Front face
        0, 1, 2,
        1, 2, 3,
        //Back face
        4, 5, 6,
        5, 6, 7,
        //Right face
        1, 3, 5,
        3, 5, 7,
        //Left face
        0, 2, 4,
        2, 4, 6,
        //Top face
        0, 1, 5,
        0, 4, 5,
        //Bottom face
        2, 3, 7,
        2, 6, 7
    };

    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC ibDesc;
    ZeroMemory(&ibDesc, sizeof(D3D11_BUFFER_DESC));
    ibDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_IMMUTABLE;
    ibDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_INDEX_BUFFER;
    ibDesc.ByteWidth = sizeof(UINT) * 36;

    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA ibSub;
    ZeroMemory(&ibSub, sizeof(D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA));
    ibSub.pSysMem = indices;

    HR(mDevice->CreateBuffer(&ibDesc, &ibSub, &mBoxIB));

    //Create Constant Buffer
    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC cbDesc;
    ZeroMemory(&cbDesc, sizeof(D3D11_BUFFER_DESC));
    cbDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    cbDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_CONSTANT_BUFFER;
    cbDesc.ByteWidth = sizeof(XMFLOAT4X4);

    HR(mDevice->CreateBuffer(&cbDesc, NULL, &mBoxCB));
```

Also, I double checked everything, so everything is bound to the pipeline, etc.

If someone could help, that would be great!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is that you use only 8 vertices, which is not correct in case of a cube since for each face vertex needs different uv coordinates (it will also be the same with normals if you need them later).

So you need to create 4 vertices per face, in order to have correct uv set for each of them.

Here is an example in [DirectX Toolkit](http://directxtk.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Src/GeometricPrimitive.cpp)

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you have such a texture seems to be the problem that the texture size is not as big as the cube side size. This way it will replicate as many times as it need to fill the whole side of the cube.

What happends if you enlarge the texture file by lets say 10 times?

Comment: Trying that out... Thanks!

Comment: Maybe I am wrong, but in my opinion it is either the size of the texture file or the scaling on the x, y and z axis

Comment: Nope, doesn't work :( Another idea? Edit: By that I mean, the cube still has the same texture, like it was before

Comment: A long time ago I also created an 3D box with a texture attached to it. However that was in openGL. I could post the code for you, however I doubt that it is helpfull for you. Since you are using Directx 11

Comment: Yeah, that would probably not help because the error is in my code, and it's probably a basic thing, but thanks though!